# What happens to Scotland energy if it leaves the UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, european-union, scotland, energy-policy

If Scotland leaves the UK and joins the EU, does its current arrangement with England change?

I understand the EU has some sort of a system to distribute energy among members. If Scotland becomes part of that system, could Scotland leaving the UK result in rising energy prices in England for example?

Comment: Not a full answer, but is Scottish energy sold to UK customers at a discounted price in some way?  Or is this question also concerned about the effects on UK trade balance in goods and services?

Comment: I would assume that everything is up for negotiation in connection with the split (which Scotland does not have the right to do unilaterally without parliamentary assent). So, it isn't clear to me that this has a well defined answer.

Comment: Scotland's "current arrangement" with England is that they are part of the same kingdom.  So of course that will change if Scotland leaves the UK (whether or not it joins the EU, and Scotland taking energy resources out of the UK will also affect energy markets in England regardless of whether Scotland joins the EU).

Comment: I am voting to close as the question lacks research and details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scotland would physically remain part of the British Isles, so there would need to be international treaties between Scotland and the UK and between the EU and the UK to cover this and many other issues. The EU has *given itself* rules. But the admission of a new member would be a rules change, too, which needs to be ratified by all existing members. The necessary unanimity to admit Scotland would be sufficient to alter any other internal agreement, depending on the political will at the time.

Comment: There are in principle significant unanswered questions on the “divorce” side as well, where in principle the UK government would be negotiating with itself in deciding those treaties at the point of separation (assuming a peaceful constitutional transition).

Answer (score 5):

Currently, the only countries to which Scotland exports electrical energy are power-hungry England and the not so power-hungry Wales, Northern Ireland, and Republic of Ireland. There are no interconnectors between Scotland and mainland Europe. There is a planned interconnector between Scotland and Norway, but (a) that has been on hold since 2020,and (b) the primary purpose of that interconnector appears to be to give Norway increased access to power-hungry England.

There are multiple existing interconnectors between England and mainland Europe, including one to Norway. The flow of energy however is mostly to rather than from England. To whom is Scotland going to export electrical power, if not to power-hungry England? England has other options if Scotland decides to get greedy.

Comment: "power-hungry England" Presumably,  the pun is intended.

Comment: @ohwilleke It was intentional. You caught me.

Comment: @ohwilleke That said, England imports a lot more electrical power than it exports, and the imbalance is growing as England is trying to wean itself from coal.

Comment: +1  Wouldn't Scotland just become a new counterparty on EPEX?

Answer (score 1):

If I am not mistaken, the energy policy of EU is still largely a matter of member states as opposed to the European Commission.

This means that if Scotland becomes a member of EU, the Scottish Government would probably play an active role in negotiating energy policies with England (whatever the country would be called by then).

Much of the outcome depends on negotiation itself, which we would not know until the hypothetical scenario comes to pass.